# Como fazer consulta com elasticsearch-dsl?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Estou começando a fazer consultas com elasticsearch_dsl e estou me perdendo para retorna meu objeto pelo nome do produto.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, connections, Q

client = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'elk-site.kalunga.com.br', 'port': 80, 'use_ssl': False}])


res=client.get(index='produto', id='217928')
print(res['_source'])
```

Json saida feito pelo id.

```
{
   "produto":[
      {
         "CD_PRODUTO":"217928",        
         "DS_Classificacao":"Notebooks, Tablets & PCs",
         "DS_Grupo":"Computadores",
         "DS_Subgrupo":"Computadores PCs",
         "NM_Fabricante_Fantasia":"HP",
         "NM_Produto":"Computador Pav.A6510BR AMD X2 4050E 2.1ghz 1gb 160gb Dvd-rw HP CX 1 UN"
      }
   ]
}
```

Quando tento fazer a consulta usando o Search do elasticsearch-dsl não obtenho retorno algum.
O que estaria faltando na query ?

```
    produto = 'Computador Pav.A6510BR AMD X2 4050E 2.1ghz 1gb 160gb Dvd-rw HP CX 1 UN'
    
    s = Search(using=client)
    
    result = s.query("match", query='Computador Pav.A6510BR AMD X2 4050E 2.1ghz 1gb 160gb Dvd-rw HP CX 1 UN', fields=['NM_Produto', 'body'])

    print(result ['_source'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o uso do método `query` esteja equivocado. O ideal seria usar o MultiMatch.

Tente usar

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import MultiMatch

(...)

result = s.MultiMatch("match", query='Computador Pav.A6510BR AMD X2 4050E 2.1ghz 1gb 160gb Dvd-rw HP CX 1 UN', fields=['NM_Produto', 'body'])
```

Maiores detalhes na [documentação](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html)

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 2):

Se sua busca é apenas em 1 campo, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': es_settings.ELASTICSEARCH_HOST, 'port': es_settings.ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}])
s = Search(using=es, index="produto")
s = s.query(Q("match", NM_Produto='Computador Pav.A6510BR AMD X2 4050E 2.1ghz 1gb 160gb Dvd-rw HP CX 1 UN'))

print("Query Elastic: ")
print(s.to_dict())

# Executa a query
response = s.execute()

for hit in s:
    print(hit.to_dict())
```

Se você precisa buscar em mais de um campo o correto é usar MultiMatch, nesse caso a query ficaria assim:

```
    es = Elasticsearch([{'host': es_settings.ELASTICSEARCH_HOST, 'port': es_settings.ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}])
    s = Search(using=es, index="produto")
s = s.query(MultiMatch(query='Computador Pav.A6510BR AMD X2 4050E 2.1ghz 1gb 160gb Dvd-rw HP CX 1 UN', fields=['NM_Produto', 'body']))

    print("Query Elastic: ")
    print(s.to_dict())
    
    # Executa a query
    response = s.execute()
    
    for hit in s:
        print(hit.to_dict())
```

Maiores detalhes na [documentação](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

Espero ter ajudado